touchstart event listener causing glitches in JavaScript game animation
I've made a Flappy Bird clone using vanilla JavaScript.
It runs pretty well on all non-mobile browsers.
However, when I play it using Chrome or Safari on iPhone, the tapping meant to make the bird jump causes the sliding obstacles to glitch (briefly shake in place). This happens every time I tap but only when I tap.
All of my animations use requestAnimationFrame().
I thought increased load during implementation of the jump() logic would be the cause, but the issue persists even after I have disabled:
-jump()
-crash detection
-gravity
-score tracker
Essentially, the only thing left running are my obstacles animation and the 'touchstart' event listener with no callbacks, yet the issue persists.
I tried preventDefault() on the event listener, but still to no avail.
Here is the animation which slides the objects:
function runShips() {
    //create random ship every 5 seconds
    generateShipsInterval();

    let previousTime = null;

    function slideShipsAnimation(currentTime) {
        if (!previousTime) {
            previousTime = currentTime;
        }
        let dt = (currentTime - previousTime) / 1000;
        document.querySelectorAll('.ships').forEach(ship => {
            ship.style.left = `${(parseFloat(getComputedStyle(ship).left) - 3 * dt * 60)}px`;
        });

        previousTime = currentTime;
        loops.slideShipsAnimation = requestAnimationFrame(slideShipsAnimation);
    }
    loops.slideShipsAnimation = requestAnimationFrame(slideShipsAnimation);

    //clear ships that are out of the screen every 10 seconds
    clearShipsInterval();
}

and here is my event handler whose logic I have disabled:
if (isMobile()) {
    //listen for tap
    document.addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        handleTap();
    });
}

function handleTap() {
    if (mode === gameStates.start) {
        getReady();
        return
    }
    if (mode === gameStates.play) {
        jump();
        return
    }
    if (laughingElon.style.display === 'block') return

    if (mode === gameStates.crash) {
        getReady();
        return
    }
    if (mode === gameStates.ready) {
        startGame();
        jump();
        return
    }
}

function jump() {
    // const x = 32;

    // birdFrames.forEach((frame, index) => {
    //     setTimeout(() => {
    //         bird.src = frame;
    //     }, index * x);
    // });

    // velocity = -9.5;
}

